# How to use 2 Passed Parameters to Change URL With htaccess?

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Say if I had a url that looked like:

```
localhost/category.php?id=name&phrase=something
```

What .htaccess rewrite rule code can I use to make it look like:

```
localhost/name/something
```

The following is what my .htaccess file currently looks like:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^/?article/([^/]*)$ /article.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^/?wrestler/([^/]*)$ /wrestler.php?id=$1 [L]

# Removes the .php extension from pages
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [L]
```

Any thoughts guys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# external redirect from /category.php?id=name&phrase=something to /name/something
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+category\.php\?id=([^&]+)&phrase=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2? [R=302,L]

# skip files and directories from rewrites
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^/?article/([^/]+)/?$ article.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^/?wrestler/([^/]+)/?$ wrestler.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]

# Removes the .php extension from pages
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ category.php?id=$1&phrase=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: What I was trying to do was match /name/keyword and then redirect (internally) to my /category.php?id=name&keyword=something

Comment: When I try typing in something like http://localhost/name/something/ a  404 Not Found Error is coming up.

Comment: Did you add latest rule in your .htaccess?

Comment: It works brother! Thanks very much. Do you recommend any reading resources on this .htaccess stuff? It's so incredibly confusing.

Comment: Glad to know it worked. For me best reference has been http://askapache.com website